# Including wp-blog-header.php creates multiple <body> tags

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I was having a problem with a page not calling the onload function in a body tag. After some investigation, I've simplified the issue to see that when I include wp-blog-header.php, it creates multiple  tags and removes the onload attribute. Here's a sample of the over-simplification.

The following php script:

```
<?php require( '../../wp-blog-header.php' ); ?>
<body class="a">
Hello World
</body>
```

Generates the following HTML in the browser:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <body>
      Hello World
    </body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Further, if I **Remove wp-blog-header.php** and use only this as my php script:

```
<body class="a">
Hello World
</body>
```

It correctly outputs the following HTML in the browser:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body class="a">
    Hello World
  </body>
</html>
```

What gives? I just did a clean update of Wordpress (4.1) and haven't messed with any system files.

Comment: Are you trying to create an additional page to integrate into your Wordpress site? Otherwise, why are you trying to include this file?

Comment: Ide recommend trying to use the get_header() function, instead of directly including the header file, which I am also confused about why you are doing that. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header

Comment: I need the $wpdb global and some things like get_current_user_id() on this external (non-Wordpress) page.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes to this and has the same issue, what had happened was the site was hacked and files had been compromised. Every index.php and functions.php file had obfuscated php code inserted at the top.